# How to update a model which contains uploaded file in .NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I have a classified ad View Model that is defined as:

```
public class ClassifiedAd
{
   public int ClassifiedAdId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, users can upload an image for the ad. This works fine during the creation of the ad.

However suppose I want to allow users to edit their classified ad, including the uploaded image. How am I supposed to populate the `ImageFile` property with the currently uploaded file when the `HttpPostedFileBase` class is abstract? How do I properly display the currently uploaded image and prevent the user from deleting it unintentionally and/or allow them to delete it properly?

Is there a way to create an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` from a `MemoryStream` of `byte array` that I'm missing here or is there some other way to deal with this issue?

Comment: You can create a different ViewModel for the edit page and skip that field.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? Why would I skip that field I want them to be able to replace current image with another one or delete current image. How can I do that by skipping the field?

Comment: Notice that it's Http*Posted*FileBase.  It only contains data that Is posted.  It isn't something that can be edited.  If the user wants to "edit" it, they upload a new file, which replaces it in the next post.  There's no way for a user to see this data, unless you extract it and then provide it in a separate image download.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I see. So the only way would be for me to extend the model to where I have another property that contains current uploaded file name and then generate some mechanism to delete the file while the HttpPostedFileBase property would only be to upload a new file. Does this sound about right?